# Calling an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 tables, courses(course_id and name) and staffs (staff_id and name) with the association of HABTM relation and a join table with course_id and staff_id. I wanted to display out the staffs that are teaching a particular course but am not sure how to go about it. Would any kind soul care to point it out?

I created the association through this

```
<% for staff in Staff.find(:all) %>
<div>
<%= check_box_tag "course[staff_ids][]", staff.id, @course.staffs.include?(staff) %>
<%= staff.name %>
</div>
```

now i want it to display only the selected without the rest of the unchecked boxes. Below are the database migration code

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :courses do |t|
      t.string :course_code
      t.string :course_name
      t.integer :year_of_study
      t.string :discipline
      t.integer :Acad_unit
      t.integer :cohort_size
      t.text :remark

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateStaffs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :staffs do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :phone
      t.string :email
      t.string :designation
      t.string :department
      t.string :location
      t.text :remark

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

 class ScheduleCourse < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :scheduleCourse do |t|
      t.belongs_to :course
      t.belongs_to :staff
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There are an infinite number of answers to this question, but knowing your specifics would help narrow down the possible answers. Can you show some code about how the tables are created, and where you want to display them?

Comment: updated some code.. Hope it explains the question clearer

Comment: Add models for exact answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have written the models: `Staff.find(id).courses`